# cocos2d - adding a node to a sprite

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a sprite which is created at the start of the program and is added to the spritebatchnode by the following code:

```
[spritebatchnode addchild:mysprite]
```

Now, i want to create a dummy ccnode (invisible node) in some point in time and add this dummy node to the sprite:

```
[mysprite addchild:dummynode]
```

With this, now i want to create another sprite (a visible one) and add it to the dummy by:

```
[dummynode addchild:sprite2]
```

However i get sigabirt error and it doesn't tell where it is. Why is this getting error? Can't i add a node to a sprite which is added previosly in a batchnode? Do i have to add mysprite to the batchnode after adding and creating all the other stuff?

note: every var is initialized in this example

More code, this is the code which is getting the error:

```
CCNode *dummy = [CCNode node];
[dummy setPosition:CGPointZero];
[mySprite addChild:dummy];
[spriteBathNode addChild:mySprite];
```

Comment: Do you get the problem when dummynode is visible?

Comment: I haven't tried, but what i do is `dummynode = [CCNode node];` I can't seem to add a node to a sprite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, apparently, I had to remove the following method for it to work:

```
[mysprite useBatchnode:spritebatchnode];
```

Solved!